# Transformer Output Problem

Tags: transformer, mains

I have this [transformer](http://www.rapidonline.com/sku/Electrical-Power/Transformers/Lighting-Transformers/60W-Lighting-transformer/72743/88-3667) which is 240VAC to 11.4VAC. But when I hook up my multimeter I am only reading about 1.2V. I have my multimeter configured to read AC and the scale is also correct. However my multimeter isn't true RMS. Could this be causing a problem? If not what else could be the problem?

Comment: it's probably not the true RMS thing; cheaper meters that aren't true RMS are usually built to give the correct reading for sinusoidal power at mains frequency on their AC settings.

Comment: Ok yeah we only have cheap meters at school where we are testing the transformer because people break them, and steal them. :@

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your link points to the description of a device marketed as a "transformer", but obviously containing much more. It seems like this device is designed specifically for the use with 12 V halogen lamps.

If it was a true transformer (and nothing more), it would work at mains frequency (50 or 60 Hz), and you would have this frequency at the input (primary) and at the output (secondary). In this case, a cheapo multimeter would likely give you an acceptable reading when you were measuring the output voltage.

Your "transformer" seems to be a switching device. I assume it works like this: The AC input voltage is rectified to DC and fed to an internal electronic switch (likely MOSFET). This electronic switch chops the input current to an AC current with a frequency of 40 kHz (cf. your link, see output frequency specification!). This AC current at 40 kHz is fed into a transformer, and the secondary side of this transformer seems to directly accessible at the output wires.

I assume your multimeter uses a low-pass filter when it measures AC voltages, and this filter blocks most of the voltage at 40 kHz, giving you a reading of only 1.2 V when you should actually see > 11 V.

To be really sure, you could measure the output voltage with an oscilloscope. I am fairly sure you would see a somewhat rectangular waveform at 40 kHz = 40000 Hz, and not a somewhat sinusoidal waveform at 50 or 60 Hz like you would with an ordinary transformer.

For a voltage with a frequency and waveform like this, I would even carefully check the manual of a good RMS multimeter because even one of those might have a low pass filter around 1 kHz.

Comment: Yes its a lighting display casing. Which has stopped working when the lights and motor are on. So I assumed it was the transformer.

Comment: Motor? It could be that it only accepts resistive loads (read: halogen or incandescent lamps) and no motors. When motors start up, they need much current, acutually they look like a short when they are just beginning to move. This might trigger the supply's protection or, if it is not protected, blow it altogether.

Comment: you are correct, these are known as "transformers" in the lighting industry but are basic switched mode power supplies, without the DC filtering stage or regulation. The name is historical, they used to use wound transformers, and still do in some cases, but often an "electronic transformer" is used for efficiency, weight, cost etc. The output waveform is messy, no meter reads it well, best tested with a lamp. Regulation is omitted so that they are dimmable, and ac is better for the lamp. Don't drive a motor with it, the output will be surge protected.

Comment: Just thought i might give you an update. I found out that it was wired [incorrectly](http://tinypic.com/r/29ghb9s/7). After I was told that the plug had been checked :L. This is [how](http://www.ultimatehandyman.co.uk/plug8.jpg) a UK plug should be wired.